# How to insert full stop mark in html5 speech recognition?

Tags: html

I am using HTML5 speechrecognition feature in my web page. Everything goes well. It used to show me "." when I said "full stop", but for the last four days it is writing down the words "full stop" instead of writing the mark "."

Any thoughts on how to achieve this?
PS: it works with question mark, comma and exclamation marks; but does not work with full stop, semi colon and colon.

Edit:
Here's the actual code I am using.

```js
window.SpeechRecognition = window.webkitSpeechRecognition || window.SpeechRecognition;
let finalTranscript = '';
let interimTranscriptNumber = 0;
let recognition = new window.SpeechRecognition();
recognition.interimResults = true;
recognition.maxAlternatives = 10;
recognition.continuous = true;
recognition.onresult = (event) => {
    let interimTranscript = '';
    interimTranscriptNumber++;
    for (let i = event.resultIndex, len = event.results.length; i < len; i++) {
        let transcript = event.results[i][0].transcript;
        if (event.results[i].isFinal) {
            finalTranscript += transcript;
        } else {
            interimTranscript += transcript;            
            createProcessSpan(interimTranscriptNumber+": "+interimTranscript);
        }
    }
    //document.querySelector('body').innerHTML = finalTranscript + '<i style="color:#ddd;">' + interimTranscript + '</>';    
    createOutputSpan(finalTranscript);
    finalTranscript = '';
}
recognition.start();
recognition.onend = function () {
    console.log('Speech recognition service disconnected');
    recognition.start();
}
```

Comment: Post your try to overcome this error.Because your question doesn't clear that what approach you are using.

Comment: I just posted the code.

Answer (score 1):

You could detect when someone actually says "full stop" and then run

```
finalTranscript.replace("full stop", ".");
```

Comment: This is useful to get the end product, but how to make sure that the transcript automatically does this. Or, why is that it used to give the mark for a few days and then decided to return words later. If you can help on that?